# How do i convert a text to column code block into a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following codes repeatedly to text to column some data. I'm repeating these lines from ("A:A") to ("DM:DM"). Sometimes the file i want to run this on will have less that that amount of columns. Even if that's the case i made the code to text to column the maximum possible amount of columns. But this makes the execution slow. I want to convert this to a loop where if the next column is blank, the execution will jump to the next block.

Can you good people suggest me a way to do that?

```
Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use offset, so in a loop `for x=1 to 10 if range("a1").offset(0,x).value<>"" then Range("A:A").offset(0,x).texttocolumns....else skip`  Or simply `columns(x).`

Comment: So 

`for x=1 to 10 
 if range("a1").offset(0,x).value<>"" 
 then Range("A:A").offset(0,x).texttocolumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
 TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
 Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
 :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`

?

Also can you explain what each line does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the code a bit and came up with this solution. I don't know if there is any better way to do this but this gets the job done.

If anyone is interested:

```
On Error Resume Next
For x = 1 To 200
If Not Range("a1").Offset(0, x).IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then 
Range("A:A").Offset(0, x).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1").Offset(0, x), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, 
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a column has any non-blank cells (formula or value) you could employ this condition:

```
If Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).CountLarge < Range("A:A").CountLarge Then
```

which will allow you to determine if a column is populated in any way and only execute your code if it is.

Be warned that the call to SpecialCells will fail if the *entire* column is non-blank.